# Unable to connect Grafana to Azure Log Analytics

Tags: azure, grafana, azure-log-analytics, azure-log-analytics-workspace

I am trying to connect Grafana to Azure Log Analytics Workspace using managed identity in a VM provided by my organization.

I keep on getting the following error:
Error connecting to Azure Log Analytics endpoint: health check failed: Post "https://api.loganalytics.io/v1/workspaces/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/query": dial tcp: lookup api.loganalytics.io: no such host (where xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx represent my Log Analytics workspace Id from Azure).

[Please see the attached image below.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAMJm.png)

How can I proceed from here.